# putting 2 textViews on top of each other

Tags: android

I want to have something where half of the text in a textView or any other kind of text display is highlighted while the other half is not.  For example

in "textView". the "text" would be in a red font and "view" would be in black.

I was thinking about doing this by putting 2 textViews directly on top of each other but I am not exactly sure how to do this.  (What kind of parameters, etc?) Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You could use a framelayout or relativelayout to stack the views.

Comment: Do you know what parameters that I would set in each of them?

Comment: TextView is able to display some HTML formatting, wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: So i could do something like this :

Comment: <font color="green">Your green text goes here.</font> as the text for the text view or would this not work

Comment: that would be great @James

Comment: If your text comes from a resource, then yes, you can include minimal html formatting as you've done here. I do it that way all the time. If you need to generate the string at runtime, it gets a little trickier; read up on "Spannable".

Comment: I would go with `Spannable`; all you need is to correctly set up a `ForegroundColorSpan` and a `BackgroundColorSpan`. Using different views would be a horrible waste.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack multiple textViews by using a *Layout* that supports this, such as a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. That said, I think the better approach (which would provide better control over the appearance) would be to create a custom view, and draw the text to the canvas yourself. You can do this with something like this (I have not tested this, but it should work - might need a few tweaks though):

```
public class TwoPartTextView extends View
{

    private CharSequence part1 = "", part2 = "";
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int color1 = Color.BLACK, color2 = Color.BLACK;
    private Context context;
    private float part1Size = 12f, part2Size = 12f;
    private int strokeWidth = 2;

    public TwoPartTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public TwoPartTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public TwoPartTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(context) {
        this.context = context;
        mPaint = new Paint();
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence part1, int color1, part1Size, CharSequence part2, int color2, part2Size, strokeWidth) {
        this.part1 = part1;
        this.color1 = color1;
        this.part1Size = part1Size;
        this.part2 = part2;
        this.color2 = color2;
        this.part2Size = part2Size;
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mPaint.setColor(color1);
        mPaint.setTextSize(part1Size);
        canvas.drawText(part1.toString(), 0, paint.getTextSize(), paint);
        mPaint.setColor(color2);
        mPaint.setTextSize(part2Size);
        canvas.drawText(part2.toString(), getWidth()/2 /* tweak as needed*/, paint.getTextSize(), paint);
    }

}
```

Then to use it, add it to XML or create it in code, then call:

```
myTwoPartTextView.setText("text", Color.RED, 12f, "View", Color.BLACK, 14f, 2);
myTwoPartTextView.setText.invalidate();
```